# Tinyos Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file

Tags: java, tinyos

When I use make command, like make mica2, in TinyOS. The following problem will occured:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
make: *** [exe0] Error 1
```

I reinstalled JAVA and add env variables, but it didn't work. I use TinyOS 2.1 and JAVA 1.5 u18. Can any one help me?

Problem solved by install JDK 1.6. Although when I run tos-check-env command, it shows me a warning that tell me its not JDK 1.4 or 1.5. Maybe it is a bug in TinyOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

an UnsupportedClassVersionError means you are trying to run byte code on an older version of the JVM than it was compiled in. You can use a class file viewer to check which version of the JDK the source code was compiled it and make sure it is compatible with JAVA 1.5 u18.

Answer (score 2):

The error you're getting means that the version of Java that's running is trying to load a class that was compiled with an incompatible version of Java.

With the information you've provided it's not possible to diagnose the problem any more specifically than this - look at any Java libraries you're using and what their required Java versions are.  If you can't find anything wrong here, you might just need to clean out some cached *.class files that were built with a version of Java before the reinstall.

Finally, if you have multiple JVMs installed be sure that `make` is using the one you expect.  It's definitely possible for you to have installation Java 1.5u18 but for the application to still be finding and using a 1.4 JVM from somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error today, and I simply solved it by installing java version 1.6 and jre6, and by making Java 1.6 version as the default version.

I also had java 1.5 installed earlier, as tos-check-env wanted me to have either java 1.4 or java 1.5 versions installed.

I also included both the java 1.5 and 1.6 versions to my classpath and ran `make micaz` again in the `/opt/tinyos-2.1.0/apps/Blink` directory and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Normally there would be a message such as

```
(Unsupported major.minor version 49.0)
```

in the first line of the exception message. However, you got

```
Bad version number in .class file
```

So maybe your class file is corrupted?

Answer (score 0):

Use sudo update-alternatives --config java and set the version you may want to use.